# Python, Copy Subfolders with its Contents into newly created Parent folders

Tags: python

I have code with this logic: Make the directory from column "Folder_Name_to_create" if it exists.
I am trying to add to this newly created directories a STATIC set of subfolders with its contents.

Getting subfolders to be copied to the newly created folder:

```
subfolders_to_create = []
for entry in pl_Template_Dir.glob('*'):
    if entry.is_dir():
        subfolders_to_create.append(entry.name)
```

Code that creates new directory if exists:

```
for folder in pl_dest['Folder_Name_to_create']:
    try:
        pathlib.Path(folder).mkdir()
    except FileExistsError:
        pass
```

What I am trying:

```
for sd in subfolders_to_create:
            (pl_dest / sd).mkdir()
```

error: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'mkdir'`

`pl_dest` dataframe:

````
```
     Folder_Name_to_create
0  O:\Stack\Over\Flow\2010 
1  O:\Stack\Over\Flow\2011 
```
````

Im having trouble putting this together. I want to create new directories if they exist and bring in the the Template Subfolders and contents to each newly created directory.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `mkdir` on DataFrame, which has no such method. Although `pl_dest / sd` appends subdirectories to all parent folders in df, the call still returns a dataframe. You should make individual call on every element of the new df. It would look something like this:

```
for subfolder in subfolders_to_create:
    for folder_to_create in pl_dest['Folder_Name_to_create'] / subfolder:
        # exist_ok=True instead of try/catch
        folder_to_create.mkdir(exist_ok=True, parents=True)
```

Edit:

To copy subfolders with contents use shutils. In this example subfolders_to_create contains paths, not only relative names.

```
import shutils

for src_dir in subfolders_to_create:
    for dst_dir in pl_dest['Folder_Name_to_create']:
        shutils.copytree(src_dir, dst_dir)
```

Comment: thanks! works well! although the contents of the subfolders are not being copied over but the subfolders are being created! IE word documents are not being created and copied over

Comment: Sry, I missed that. The answer is edited now. You just have to add append "entry" instead of "entry.name"

Comment: Hey , i believe you meant `shutil` without the s.  Getting an error though `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'I. Original Data'` Which is a subfolder with some word documents in it.